# How should I use Gauss Divergence theorem to solve this Surface Integral?

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

Let $V = \left( (x,y,z) \in R^3 : 1/4 \le x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \le 1\right)$

and $\vec{F} = \dfrac{x\hat{i} + y\hat{j} + z\hat{k}}{ (x^2 + y^2 +z^2)^2}$ for $(x,y,z)\in V$
Let $\hat{n}$ denote the outward unit normal vector to the boundary of V and $S$ denote the part $\left(x^2+ y^2 + z^2 = 1/4\right)$ of the boundary of $V$

Then  find $\displaystyle \int \int F.\hat{n} dS$

I want to evaluate this surface integral with help of Gauss Divergence theorem

However ,my main issue is which surface should I use ?From what I have learnt the body used for Gauss Divergence theorem must be the outer boundary for surface.

So, in this case If I take the outer boundary itself to be $x^2 +y^2 + z^2 =1/4$ then ,

$\vec{F} = \dfrac{\vec{r}}{r^4}$ So $\nabla .F = \dfrac{-1}{r^4}$

Using this the integral is given by : (After simplifying in terms of Spherical Coordinates)

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{1/2} 1/{{\rho}^2} sin \phi d \rho d \phi d \theta$ .

However this last integral is undefined .

Can anyone tell me what is the correct way to solve this question

Thank You.

Comment: You are told to use $V$ but the neither does your integral reflect this nor is your chosen surface the entire boundary for $V$. However I believe the best way to compute this surface integral is directly and not use divergence theorem.

Comment: @NinadMunshi  :Actually In my book this is  solved with the help of surface integral , However the outward normal vector is taken  as $-\hat{N}$ ie $-2x\hat{i} -2y\hat{j} -2z\hat{k}$ Can you please explain why is the normal vector taken to be negative and why isn't it positive ?

Comment: If you were to point an arrow on the surface S away from the region V, which region would it be pointing to?

Comment: @NinadMunshi: I am trying to solve the question with your hint but I am not getting anywhere. The outward normal vector for region $V$ should be outside the surface right ?  because our region $V$  =$1/4 \le x^2 + y^2 +z^2 \le 1$ and when I draw the outside normal vector on $V$ it should point away from $S$, I don't Understand why are we taking a negative here ?                                                                                           Can you please post a complete answer to resolve this doubt ? I would be very grateful .